# how to generate empty css items with compass sass?

Tags: compass-sass

compass defaultly not getnerate css items ,but I want to keep these items alway,because sometime I can use firebug code these empty items .any way to keep them, how to set?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quick solution: added a comment in each non-deletable property to keep.

```
.help_center {
  /*! keep */
  .nav {
    /*! keep */
  }
}
```

The [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments) says:

> When the first letter of a comment is !, the comment will be interpolated and always rendered into css output even in compressed output modes. This is useful for adding Copyright notices to your generated CSS.